# Can i make 64 - bit Firefox use 32 - bit Java and how?

Tags: sound, firefox, 64-bit, 32-bit, webex

I am a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu, so please endure my ignorance... I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 for safety reasons and to have a desktop with no distractions for study. The Study I am attending is mostly online via WebEx.

For this purpose, I have followed another post's instructions in order to install Firefox 32 bit version and Java. It worked like a charm.

So today, I have tried to watch a video one of the professors put up on the site, but it needed flash plugin, which I installed. I restarted my Firefox, and it's back to 64bit version.
I have been at it for a week now setting everything up so I can listen to lectures and it is becoming a bit frustrating.
Do I need a separate browser so see content that requires flash player or is it possible to have one 32 bit Firefox browser that supports everything?

EDIT: I have changed the question after some reading other posts regarding sound in webex. Solutions there did not help me.

Comment: Why you didn't try 64 bit only. The Java plugin works fine in 64 bit.

Comment: I have tried, but it seems in 64 bit version of the browser,  when I go into a WebEx meeting room, I cannot get a sound (in other words, I can't listen to lectures).

Comment: Have you tried another (64-bit)-browser?

Comment: why yes! I have tried google chrome, chromium, opera and to no avail since cisco webex online room operates on 32 bit java. I have also tried to find my answer on other posts here on ask ubuntu. :(